# Call two pandas columns in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pandas, lambda

I have a bunch of URLs I am trying to write to files. I store the URLs in a pandas dataframe.

The dataframe has two columns: `url` and `id`. I am trying to request each URL from `url` and write it to a file named `id`.

Here is what I got so far:

```
def get_link(url): 
    file_name = os.path.join('/mypath/foo/bar', df.id)
    try: 
        r = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failded to get " + url)
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f: 
            f.write(r.text)

df.url.apply(lambda l: get_link(l))
```

But when I call the function, it obvioulsly fails, since `os.path.join` expects a `string` and not a `series`. Hence I get the error `join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'Series'`

Any ideas how I can simultaenously call `df.id` and `df.url`?

Thank you/R

Comment: As an aside: Do not use a catchall `Exception`. Keep it specific, that inadvertently swallows other issues you may not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enhance your function to take the `id_` parameter in addition to `url`.

```
def get_link(url, id_): 
    file_name = os.path.join('/mypath/foo/bar', id_)
    try: 
        r = requests.get(url)
    except ConnectionError, MissingSchema as e:
        print("Failded to get " + url)
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f: 
            f.write(r.text)
```

Then just iterate through your dataframe to call your function.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    get_link(url=row.url, id_=row.id)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a great deal!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows and then get values per rows by `x.url` and `x.id`, becasue working with `Series` with index by columns, here `url` and `id`:

```
def get_link(x): 
    print (x) 
    file_name = os.path.join('/mypath/foo/bar', x.id)
    try: 
        r = requests.get(x.url)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failded to get " + x.url)
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f: 
            f.write(r.text)

df.apply(get_link, axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'url':['url1','url2'],
                   'id':[1,2]})

print (df)
   id   url
0   1  url1
1   2  url2

def get_link(x):
    print (x) 
    print ('url is: {}'.format(x.url))
    print ('id is: {}'.format(x.id))

df.apply(get_link, axis=1)

id        1
url    url1
Name: 0, dtype: object
url is: url1
id is: 1
id        2
url    url2
Name: 1, dtype: object
url is: url2
id is: 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very illustrative and provides me with some new knowledge!

Comment: Hmmm, I am curious, why do you think `iterrows` is better? I think the best is [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002) it.

Comment: `iterrows` is not recommended for operations than can be vectorized.  I don't believe url requests fall into this category, however.

Comment: Sorry if I disappointed you! It is just that I understand `iterrows` - I used it before. I am new to the solution you provided and don't quite understand it yet. It still works well! Why would you try not to use `iterrows`? Hope that is OK! Thank you in any case!

Comment: If simply loop values it working both solutions.
But generally the best is avoiding iterrows, because the slowiest

Comment: Understood! Thank you!